# XGboost in Weka

Tags: plugins, weka, xgboost

How to install the XGboost package in Weka? I found this link said that we can call XGboost from Rplugin package.

http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/RPlugin/index.html

Is there any other approach to integrate XGBoost into Weka ?

Comment: What's wrong with using RPlugin, for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

XGBoost4J [1] is a popular implementation for Java.
There is also a Weka wrapper for XGBoost4J, see [2].

[1] https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/javadocs/index.html

[2] https://github.com/SigDelta/weka-xgboost